# Attach clothesline to wall when there's some grainy material inside the wall

Tags: drywall, walls, studs, drywall-anchor, stucco

I want to attach a couple of clotheslines to an interior wall. They need to be attached to a solid piece of timber or into masonry, but the wall is plasterboard (drywall). So I plan to attach these pieces of decking to the wall first, and then attach the clotheslines to them.

[image: floorplan showing the wall separating the toilet room from the laundry]

[image: photo of the wall with the pieces of decking next to it]

But, I'm not sure how to attach the timber. Until now I thought I could just drive a couple of screws through them into the studs — but the studs are hard to find. I tried knocking on it and then drilling where it sounded less hollow, but I couldn't tell what I was drilling into. I cut a section of plaster out and found this:

[image: closeup of cut-out section of plasterboard, revealing the old wall behind]

My guess is that this is an old stucco wall behind plasterboard, which had been attached with some kind of putty (the yellow stuff). It seems that it sounded less hollow at this point because of the putty, not because there's a stud there.

Cutting just a little deeper, I found this grainy material. It looks a bit like cement mix, but with very little actual cement. It's soft and easy to drill into.

[image: closeup of the next layer down, showing a loose grainy/sandy material]

I tried a stud finder too, but it only seems to agree with the knocking method. There doesn't seem to be much of a pattern for where it thinks there are studs, which makes me think it's just more putty.

I'm not sure what to do next. Should I cut into other parts of the wall, hoping to find something useful?

Comment: It looks like drywall placed over a plaster and lath wall.  There should be studs behind the plaster, but might be looking at an inch or more till the studs.  Studs should be about 16 inches centre to centre, one at the end the next about 18 from the outside edge(give or take an inch).

Comment: Wow ok, I didn't know plaster and lath was used much or at all here (Australia), but you might be right. Assuming that's what it is, should I avoid attaching to the laths? And should I continue drilling to find the studs — and if so, how would I know whether I was drilling into a lath or a stud?

Comment: How did you identify it as plaster and lath? I haven't encountered it before, but I would have expected it to be less grainy.

Comment: Guessing really.  Might just be plaster/stucco.  Laths are usually very thin wood, maybe 1/4 to 1/2(6 to 13mm) inch thick.

Comment: it's common for the inner layers of stucco to have a lot of sand filler (which makes it grainy), From the photo it's impossible to say if it is stucco over lath or stucco over brick.